# Polymer google-signin element gets Cannot read property 'currentUser' of null

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to get the `google-signin` element to work with just adding this to my HTML:

```
<google-signin clientId="[my-client-id]" scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"></google-signin>
```

The Sign-in button shows up on the page, but when I click it, I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'currentUser' of null
```

I'm testing it out on just `localhost`, so I'm not sure if this is a client id domain issue, or if there's more I need to do in JS to handle the return object?

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `client-id` instead of `clientId`.

```
<google-signin client-id="[my-client-id]" scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"></google-signin>
```

The [google-signin](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin) documentation for this attribute doesn't match with the actual [code](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/blob/master/google-signin.html#L17).

Comment: WOW! Google, seriously get it together. Thanks @dreyescat! I spent far too long trying to troubleshoot that.